# IBM BPM 8.5 Multi-instance sequence flow by custom order

Tags: sequence, ibm-bpm, multi-instance-deployment

Have loan task (see example below)  which is separating by multi-instance loop:

```
loans[
   [loanNo:1, dueDate: 2020-10-10],
   [loanNo:2, dueDate: 2020-05-05],
   [loanNo:3, dueDate: 2020-07-07]
]
```

How to make sequence loop to loop by custom order, not by index (0,1,2) but by dueDate so that first element will be closest date 2020-05-05, then 2020-07-07 and etc..

Comment: Format the question and make it proper readable for all.

Comment: How to make sequence multi-instance loop to loop by custom order, not by index (0,1,2) but by dueDate so that array with closest date will be passed first?

Is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to order your array by dueDate after to pass it to your multi-instance loop.

You could insert in your process a script step before your multi-instance task that do this ordering:

```
tw.local.orderedLoans = loans.sort(function(a, b) { 
  return a.dueDate.localeCompare(b.dueDate) 
});
```

And then pass the tw.local.orderedLoans to the task